# Website redirect based on URL to App installed in Windows Server IIS and Newer Azure App service

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, windows, azure

Looking for a design solution.

We are currently migrating our old site installed in Windows Server IIS to Cloud-based Azure App service or Azure Service fabric.

We have multiple clients but one of the requirement is to move clients one by one.

I.e They want us to use the same DNS, but based on brands it should route to the new or old site.

so for example, we have 2 brands

Brand 1  - moved to a new site
Brand 2 - still using the old site.

So we when the request comes

- For www.Mysite.com/brand1 then it should call Site hosted in Azure.
- For www.Mysite.com/brand2 it should call old site hosted in windows
  server IIS.

Is this feasible? If yes what are the options I have?

I saw options to Redirect a Domain by modifying .htaccess file.

Currently looking for options to finalize the design approach i.e moving all client at once or moving one by one. But later is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a good business case for having an azure application gateway as its made for   redirecting traffic based on the route requested. the gateway would need to be register under the domain name you want visible and you would then configure the routing rules on the app gateway resource. your azure resource and your on prem resource would be considered your backend pools

www.Mysite.com/brand1 -> point to my new cloud server pool

www.Mysite.com/brand2-> point to my existing app server pool

Linking the azure docs on this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use an Azure Function to handle the redirect.  I have done something similar in order to create our own short urls for text messages.  Before redirecting you can inspect the original url to determine where to redirect too.

[Check out this link](https://blog.yannickreekmans.be/use-an-azure-function-to-redirect-urls/)